# Standard for software comparison

Tags: performance, comparison, standards

I'm developing a preventive maintenance strategy for an industrial plant based on RCM (Reliability Centered Maintenance) methodology. For this job, I need to choose one CMMS (Computerized maintenance management system) among several options but I need to do it in a clever way.

Is there some technical procedure to make a Comparative Assessment of Software Programs and get to know what is the better CMMS option? Any standard, table or matrix?

Thank you so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Comment: Your question is not a problem, the standard format is something like this  "what I am trying to do" - "what I have tried"  -  "what went wrong" all backed up with code examples

Comment: Thank you.Do you know about another place more appropriate for my question?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, maybe a forum for your industry? Maybe specific subreddit? Somewhere which isn't as specific as stack overflow

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an insteresting document with a Comparative Assessment of Software
Programs very useful for me developed by the IRIS Center at the University of Maryland.

[Comparative Assessment of Software
Programs for the Development of
Computer-Assisted Personal Interview
(CAPI) Applications](http://siteresources.worldbank.org/INTSURAGRI/Resources/7420178-1294259038276/CAPI.Software.Assessment.Main.Report.pdf)

This scientific article could be useful as well:

[Comparative Assessment of Software Quality Classification Techniques: An Empirical Case Study](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B%3AEMSE.0000027781.18360.9b)

**EDIT**

There are Sites like Quora that are better places to make this kind of questions